# How can I check if a collection contains an item using JSP/EL/JSTL

Tags: jsp, collections, jstl, el

I am using Java 8, Tomcat 8, with Servlet 3.1.0, JSP 2.0 and JSTL 1.2.

I expected to be able to do the following. However, it does not work.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${itemList}" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
    <td>${item.itemCode}</td>
    <td>${item.displayName}</td>
    <td>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${user.favourites.contains(item)}">Yes</c:when>
        <c:otherwise>No</c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

where `user.favourites` is a `Set` of `item`s

Could it be that I do not have the right versions of the dependencies. My POM contains;

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

`servlet-api` and `jsp-api` are provided by Tomcat. Is the version for `jstl` correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that it *does* work, but that I had another issue at hand.

My entities (`item` and `user`) are coming from Hibernate, from two different DAOs in two different queries, and so the `item` in the `favourites` list was a different object to the `item` in the `itemList`.

I had not implemented (overridden) the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in my `User` and `Item` classes, and so the `Collection.contains()` was just looking at object identity not equivalence.

As soon as I implemented `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, it all worked as expected.

The way I found this out was I decided to implement a custom TLD function that invoked the `Collection.contains(...)` method, and then noticed that even that was returning `false`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the contains function provided in JSTL tag library. Kindly find more details @ [JSTL fn:contains() Function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_contains.htm)

This would help you.

Comment: From what I have seen, `fn:contains` is for checking whether one String contains the value in the other String, not for checking whether  collection contains the given item

Comment: You can refer to this www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/J2EE/Q_24847712.html, the 4th comment uses this contains method for the same.

Comment: I suspect it may have worked because the stringified representation of the array contained the stringified representation of the object. In effect it did a `array.toString().contains(object.toString())`. A convenient fluke, not something I would want to rely upon

Comment: If one value of a substring of another value you would have an erroneous match.